# I would like the suspension specs on my 2002 Rocky Mountain Element. Any help is appreciated

Tags: suspension

I'm riding a 2002 Rocky Mountain Element.  It has a blown shock in the rear.  I would like to find the specs for replacement of the Fox Float R 2002 shock.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Go to Page 8. https://www.ridefox.com/fox_tech_center/owners_manuals/02_RearShocks_en.pdf

Answer (score 4):

Via https://www.bikes.com/sites/default/files/2004_RMB_TECH_MANUAL_EN.pdf page 47

> Shock size is 6.5" eye-eye, 1.5" stroke.

Note: Thats a 2004 spec so check the eye-to-eye length, if thats a match theres a high probability that the stroke length is the same.

Ebay/Amazon is your best bet for random shocks, you don't need to replace with a Fox. While OEM shocks are custom tuned for a given bike model I imagine you'd just prefer to be back on the trail so don't stress too much about an exact shock match.

The other alternative is to send the shock to a professional for a rebuild. The pro shock mechanics have access to almost anything via their channels.

Comment: Modern Fox shocks all have a 4-digit code that is the unique ID for each shock tune. You can lookup these shock tunes on the Fox website. I don't know if that practice was in place in 2004, but that might be helpful to the OP too.